# Box-drawing characters cause error - Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: symbols, listings, unicode, code, listingsutf8

I have a code snippet wrapped inside a `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
printf("┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓\n");
printf("┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫\n");
printf("┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛\n");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But I get this errors:

```
Package inputenc: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
```

LaTeX doesn't like those ┏ ━ ┳ ┓┣ ┫┗ ┻ ┛ [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)

---

I've tried to add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

or

```
\usepackage{unixode}
```

..., but nothing worked.

Comment: The culprit is listings. Either literate the characters or use a utf-8 enabled package for listing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\lstset{literate= {┏}{{\pmboxdrawuni{250F}}}1 
                  {━}{{\pmboxdrawuni{2501}}}1 
                  {┳}{{\pmboxdrawuni{2533}}}1
                  {┓}{{\pmboxdrawuni{2513}}}1 
                  {┣}{{\pmboxdrawuni{2523}}}1 
                  {╋}{{\pmboxdrawuni{254B}}}1
                  {┫}{{\pmboxdrawuni{252B}}}1
                  {┗}{{\pmboxdrawuni{2517}}}1
                  {┛}{{\pmboxdrawuni{251B}}}1
                  {┻}{{\pmboxdrawuni{253B}}}1
                  }
\begin{document}
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓

\begin{lstlisting}
printf("┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓\n");
printf("┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫\n");
printf("┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛\n");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]